# Sometimes have click twice on the button for quantity change on the cart page on Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopping-cart

-

```
                    <input id="updates_large_{{ item.key }}" class="cart__qty-input" type="number"
                    name="updates[]" value="{{ item.quantity }}" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*"
                    data-quantity-input data-quantity-item="{{ forloop.index }}" data-role="product-quantity-desktop" readonly>

                    <button type="submit" class="btnqty qtyplus icon icon-plus" value="+" onclick="quantityUp()">+</button>

                    <script>

                      function quantityDown(e, form) {
                        document.getElementById("updates_large_{{ item.key }}").stepDown();
                      }

                      function quantityUp(e, form) {
                        document.getElementById("updates_large_{{ item.key }}").stepUp();
                      }
            
                    </script>
```

On mobile I have to sometimes click twice on the quantity up and down button.

Comment: It's debut theme. What happens is it change the quantity on input but price does not change.